# Чем можно заменить анимацию box-shadow

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Есть такая анимация на CSS, которая использует свойство `box-shadow`.
Но для браузера это тяжело. Есть ли решения, что можно сделать вместо этого? Можно и на JS и CSS, и SMIL SVG

```css
.waypoint-marker {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  animation: out 2s infinite ease-out;
  background: #cf3c3c;
}

@keyframes out {
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(207 60 60 / 80%);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="waypoint-marker"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' анимация box-shadow сильно нагружает CPU. Можно создать чистый html, туда засунуть эту анимацию, нажать в хроме Shift + Esc (инспектор хрома) и увидеть, что нагружается CPU. А если таких мигающих точек будет много, они в разных местах и разные тайминги анимации, то ещё больше нагрузки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такую вам конструкцию сваял) @Alexandr_TT полностью прав, это можно заменить свойствами `transform: scale` и `opacity`

```css
.waypoint-marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.waypoint-marker::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.waypoint-marker>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animate 1s ease infinite;
}

.waypoint-marker>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animate 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="waypoint-marker"><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Или чуть проще:

```css
.waypoint-marker {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.waypoint-marker::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: .5
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="waypoint-marker"></div>
```

**SMIL SVG**

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewbox="10 10 50 50">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" fill="red" r="1">
    <animate attributeName="r" from="0" to="10" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" from="0.5" to="0" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" fill="red" r="1.5">
</svg>
```

SMIL SVG. Добавим паузу между анимацией:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewbox="10 10 50 50">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" fill="red" r="1">
    <animate id="an1" attributeName="r" from="0" to="10" dur="1s" begin="0s;an1.end+1s" repeatCount="1"/>
    <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" from="0.5" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0s;an2.end+1s" repeatCount="1"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" fill="red" r="1.5">
</svg>
```

Comment: интересно! ----

Comment: ооооо, благодарю! Я обязательно тоже научусь делать SMIL, вроде не сложно

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте вариант CSS+SVG

Анимация основана на  изменении `scale()`  svg кругов

```
@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(8.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

Можете настроить по своему вкусу продолжительность, цвет и количество анимированных кругов:

```css
rect {
  fill: #4e4e4e;
}
circle {
  fill: #65ff78;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
svg > circle:last-child {
  fill: #35ffc3;
  opacity: 1;
}
#rp1 {
  animation: ripple1 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(8.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
#rp2 {
  animation: ripple2 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(3.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
  }
}
#rp3 {
  animation: ripple3 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(3.5);
  }
}
#rp4 {
  animation: ripple4 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%">
<defs>
  <g id="anims">
    <circle id="rp1" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp2" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp3" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp4" r="1em" />
  </g>
</defs>
<rect height="100%" width="100%" />
<use xlink:href="#anims" x="50%" y="50%"/>
<circle r="0.5em" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: подскажите, а как на smill это будет выглядеть?

Comment: плюс тут четыре разные анимации, скорее всего, это тоже будет весьма тяжело для браузера

Comment: @МихаилКамахин также, если интересно дам вечером ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Я сейчас занимаюсь оптимизацией анимацией на сайте, которые жрут очень много CPU, поэтому такой штукой занимаюсь

Comment: @МихаилКамахин всего тут две анимации scale() кругов и их opacity В ответе я написал, исходник можно заточить под себя, например оставить только один круг

Comment: А, да, всё, понял! Благодарю! Я могу использовать только один keyframes и один circle

Comment: @МихаилКамахин да, вы всё правильно поняли!

Answer (score 4):

Мой вариант на основе ответа [`@Alexandr_TT`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}

rect {
  fill: #4e4e4e;
}

circle {
  fill: #35ffc3;
  opacity: 1;
  
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#anim-circle {
  fill: #65ff78;
  opacity: 0.3;
  animation: ripple1 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
</style>
<circle id="anim-circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="1em"></circle>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.5em"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хорошо получилось. Есть, это неуловимое, чувство вкуса :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT :)

Answer (score 3):

[BONUS]

Код анимации SVG взят из ответа @Sevastopol'

### Многократное размещение ripple окружностей на карте

Часто возникает необходимость разместить маркеры на различных картах.

Ниже показана простая техника, как это сделать, не особо вникая в тонкости SVG.

**Далее по шагам:**

- Берем растровое изображение карты и добавляем его в SVG с помощью
  тега `<image>`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
</style> 

<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 804 451" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSUE.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  </svg>    
</div>
```

- Создаем маркер, окружность и помещаем  код в секцию `<defs>` для
  дальнейшего многократного использования.
  **Обратите внимание:**  Образец можно создать с анимацией и в каждом клоне эта анимация будет работать!
- Клонируем, стилизуем, позиционируем маркеры внутри `<use>`

**Всё готово:**

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
</style> 
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 804 451">  
<defs>
  <g id="Gr1" >
     <circle cx="20" cy="20"  r="3" >
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="r" from="0" to="20" dur="1s" begin="0s;an1.end+1s"/>
      <animate id="an2" attributeName="opacity" from="0.8" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0s;an2.end+1s" />
     </circle>
  </g> 
</defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSUE.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
 <use xlink:href="#Gr1" x="125" y="195"  fill="red" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#Gr1" x="133" y="140" fill="crimson" />
     <use xlink:href="#Gr1" x="252" y="273" fill="purple" />
       <use xlink:href="#Gr1" x="48" y="285" fill="green" />
         <use xlink:href="#Gr1" x="172" y="238" fill="green" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, я это как раз и хотел сделать